# OAuth issue on HostGator

Tags: oauth, pear

I am having an issue with my website. I use HostGator and on 8/26/21 they updated
my .htaccess file and pointed to a different version of PHP than what I previously
had. This also happened back in January but I was able to revert to the version
of php I was previously using and resolved the issue myself. This time around that fix is
not working. Two major components of my website that are no longer working are:

1. OAuth
2. the following line in my php scripts (I can no longer send emails)
   require_once "Mail.php";

### OAuth issue

Back in 2015 when I originally started using OAUTH, I merely had to add the following line in my php.ini file
extension=oauth.so

OAuth is no listed as one of the php modules in HostGator but that has always been the case
https://www.hostgator.com/help/article/php-modules

When I load any webpage, I get the following error message in error_log even though I have reverted back to the previous version of PHP

PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/cpanel/ea php56/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/oauth.so'
/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/oauth.so:
cannot open shared object file:
No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

I tried using "PHP PEAR Packages" in cPanel to add OAuth. I used the following steps.

1. I searched for "oauth" in Find a “PHP Extensions and Applications Package”
2. I found "HTTP_OAuth (0.3.2)" PEAR implementation of the OAuth 1.0a specification
3. I clicked on "Install"
4. It failed. I got the following

WARNING: "pear/Console_Getopt" is deprecated in favor of "pear/Console_GetoptPlus"
pear/HTTP_OAuth can optionally use PHP extension "pecl_http" (version >= 1.6.0)
pear/PEAR requires PEAR Installer (version >= 1.10.1), installed version is 1.9.5
pear/PEAR dependency package "pear/Archive_Tar" installed version 1.4.14 is not the recommended version 1.4.4, but may be compatible, use --force to install
pear/HTTP_OAuth requires package "pear/PEAR" (version >= 1.4.0)
pear/HTTP_Request2 requires package "pear/PEAR" (version >= 1.9.2)
pear/Cache_Lite requires package "pear/PEAR" (version >= 1.10.1)
No valid packages found
install failed

I then tried to install PEAR (1.10.13) PEAR Base System. I used the following steps.

1. I searched for "PEAR" in Find a “PHP Extensions and Applications Package”
2. I found PEAR (1.10.13) PEAR Base System
3. I clicked on "Install"
4. It failed. I got the following
   WARNING: "pear/Console_Getopt" is deprecated in favor of "pear/Console_GetoptPlus"
   pear/PEAR requires PEAR Installer (version >= 1.10.1), installed version is 1.9.5
   pear/PEAR dependency package "pear/Archive_Tar" installed version 1.4.14 is not the recommended version 1.4.4, but may be compatible, use --force to install
   No valid packages found
   install failed

I then did some research. I was going to attempt to install this locally in my php folder in my home directory. I used the following steps.

1. I downloaded "oauth-1.0.0.tgz" from http://pecl.php.net/package/oauth
2. I uploaded "oauth-1.0.0.tgz" to my php folder in my home directory (I confirmed this by checking the Installed PHP Extension(s) and Application(s)in the directory)
3. I then input "oauth-1.0.0.tgz" (without quotes) in the Install a PHP Extensions and Applications Package in PHP PEAR Packages and clicked "Install Now"
4. It failed. I got the following:
   No releases available for package "pear.php.net/oauth" - package pecl/oauth can be installed with "pecl install oauth"
   install failed

At this point I am stuck. This is beyond my current skill set.

### Mail issue

the following line in my php scripts (I can no longer send emails)
require_once "Mail.php";

I get the following message in my error log
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'Mail.php' (include_path='.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/usr/share/pear')

Whatever fixes the OAuth issue should be similar to this fix as it is also a PEAR module.

Answer (score 1):

`oauth` is a pecl package, and your pear web interface probably only supports pear packages, but not pecl packages - this is why you get " No releases available for pear.php.net/oauth". Nothing you can do there on your own.

---

`HTTP_OAuth` is a pear package, but it requires `Cache_Lite`, which requires PEAR 1.10.0+, and your web server only has pear 1.9.5.

Upgrading the pear base system does not work, because the pear installer on that web server is also stuck on an older version.

You're lost there. The administrator would need to upgrade pear to 1.10.0+, then you could install http_oauth.

Comment: I think this is a correct answer.